# Replace certain strings

Tags: bash, string, replace

I've got a text file containing the following:

```
yyyy-mm-dd, 12:34/s-show/...
yyyy-mm-dd, 13:24/s-show/...
yyyy-mm-dd, 14:32/s-show/...
yyyy-mm-dd/s-show
```

Now I'd like to replace the substrings before /s-show/... of every line with another string, so that it looks like the following:

```
https://www.testpage.com/s-show/...
https://www.testpage.com/s-show/...
https://www.testpage.com/s-show/...
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Is the string before the first `/` always in time format such as `12:34`?

Comment: Naah sorry, I just updated how it generally looks

Comment: @John1024 This unfortunately keeps the dates

Comment: @X3nion Oops.  Sorry.  Try `sed -E 's@.*(/s-show)@https://www.testpage.com\1@' File`

Comment: @John1024 Why not just post it as an answer?

Comment: @John1024 Yeah that works! How can the result be sent to the same file?

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks.  @X3nion, changing the file in place uses the `-i` option whose syntax depends on whether you are using GNU sed (Linux, Windows), or BSD sed (MacOS).  I just added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ sed -E 's@.*(/s-show)@https://www.testpage.com\1@' File
https://www.testpage.com/s-show/...
https://www.testpage.com/s-show/...
https://www.testpage.com/s-show/...
https://www.testpage.com/s-show
```

To change the file in place:

```
sed -Ei 's@.*(/s-show)@https://www.testpage.com\1@' File  # GNU (Linux)
```

or:

```
sed -Ei '' 's@.*(/s-show)@https://www.testpage.com\1@' File  # BSD (MacOS)
```

How it works:

- `-E` tells sed to use extended regular expressions.  This eliminates the need for some escape characters.
- `s@old@new@` is a substitute command that looks for regular expression `old` and replaces it with `new`.
- In our case, `old` is `.*(/s-show)` which matches any number of any characters, `.*`, followed by `/s-show` where `/s-show` is saved as group 1.
- In our case, `new` is `https://www.testpage.com\1` where `\1` is replaced by group 1.

Comment: How can the sed command be made to run quietly? In this case, the output is printed also in the terminal

Comment: @X3nion If you use the `-i` option (choose the one that matches your OS), then no output should appear.  If you are using the `-i` option and output does appear, then I need more details (your OS, your _exact_ command, the _exact_ output, etc).